# Error while reading data from Realm in android

Tags: java, android, realm, android-database

I was recently introduced to Realm Database for android. It seems very easy compared to SQLite, I made a simple app to test it. The data is getting saved, but I can't retrieve it for some reason.

---

Here's the MainActivity

```
package com.fayaz.realm;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public Realm realm;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    realm=Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    //WRITE
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Add a new task")
                    .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
                    .setView(taskEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                            realm.beginTransaction();
                            Person person=realm.createObject(Person.class);
                            person.setName(task);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ADDED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            realm.commitTransaction();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    //READ
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Execute the query:
            RealmResults<Person> results = realm.where(Person.class).findAll();
            String name=results.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    realm.close();
    }
}
```

An error pops us whenever I call the function to READ Data

---

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long io.realm.internal.TableView.nativeSync(long) (tried Java_io_realm_internal_TableView_nativeSync and Java_io_realm_internal_TableView_nativeSync__J)`

Comment: What version of Realm is this? I'm pretty sure the `Realm.getInstance(Context)` constructor was deprecated in **0.88.0**, and the latest version is **1.1.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing a `RealmConfiguration` to `Realm.getInstance()` not `getApplicationContext()`. It should look something like this.

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
  .name("myrealm.realm")
  .build();
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Comment: Could you please help me, how to retrieve data from realm, I am new to this, just retrieve and display a toast. It'll be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should update to at least `Realm 1.0.0`, but the latest (at the time of writing is `Realm 1.1.1`).

You're using `Realm.getInstance(Context)` which was definitely removed at the latest in `0.91.0`.

To use Realm's latest versions, you need to use Android Studio and Gradle, add this in your project-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.1" //this line
    }
}
```

And also you need to apply the `realm-android` Gradle plugin in the module-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android' // this line
```

There isn't much point in talking about errors in outdated versions. It's probably been fixed like a year ago.

EDIT:

```
//READ
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Execute the query:
        RealmResults<Person> results = realm.where(Person.class).findAll();
        if(!results.isEmpty()) {
            Person person = results.get(0);
            String name = person.getName();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }            
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you please help me, how to retrieve data from realm, I am new to this, just retrieve and display a toast. It'll be very helpful

Comment: I can't help with the old version because it's an old version. I'm not even sure what version it is.

Comment: I just added the new dependency, you can tell me for this version!

Comment: Its working after I upgraded the gradle plugin to 1.1.0. But the Toast is displaying [Person[{name:test}], I am not getting this one! What am I doing wrong above?

Comment: Well, you **are** displaying the entire results, and not just a user :P hold on I'll edit that in

Comment: Thank you, but i figured it out.